# Primary Key cannot be displayed on web page

Tags: django

I have a customer table which has 3 columns customer_id, first_name, last_name and the customer_id is the primary key.

See my views.py:

```
def addressHome(request):
    customerList = Customer.objects.raw('select * from customers')
    print(customerList.columns)
    return render(request, "Address.html", {'customerList': customerList})
```

my models.py like this:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models

class Customer(models.Model):
     customerId = models.IntegerField(db_column='customer_id', primary_key=True, editable=False)
     firstName = models.CharField(max_length=30)
     lastName = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

And my Address.html is like this:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %} Address List Page {% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<style>
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
</style>
<table width="50%" aligh="center">
    <tr>
                <th>Cutomer ID </th>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
    </tr>
    {% for row in customerList %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ row.customer_id }} </td>
            <td>{{ row.first_name }} </td>
            <td>{{ row.last_name }}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
{% endblock %}
```

below is the effect on the web page:
[image]

So, can someone tell me why and how to fix this problem?

Comment: Have you checked the schema of this table and verified the field name?  Primary key fields have "_id" appended to them, so you might actually have to query for customer_id_id.

Comment: you don't have to use `customerId`. django orm automatically create `id` for your model object

Comment: You _might_ be asking the wrong questions. Is this a legacy database? Why are you using raw SQL in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined your primary key as `customerId`,

but you are calling the field in template as `{{ row.customer_id }}`
The `db_column` option only changes the column name in database, but you should always call it with the name defined in `Model` see [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#database-representation). This applies to all the field you have defined in template.

You should try this with `{{ row.customerId }}`.

Also the view can be transformed into

```
def addressHome(request):
    customerList = Customer.objects.all()
    return render(request, "Address.html", {'customerList': customerList})
```

And in template

```
<table width="50%" aligh="center">
    <tr>
        <th>Cutomer ID </th>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
    </tr>
    {% for row in customerList %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ row.customerId }} </td>
            <td>{{ row.firstName }} </td>
            <td>{{ row.lastName }}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```